# I Cannot Select An Item In An Access Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-forms

I have an access form that includes a combo box.

I load the values in the combo box from a value list.

While the combo box opens and I can see all the values, when I click in it I cannot select a value. I click but nothing happens. The combo box remains opened displaying all the possible values.

[image]

Here is my configuration:

[image]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the Form object itself allows edits, i.e.:

[image]

Comment: Lee Mac - that did it!! Thank you so much.